# Are vectors and matrices reference or value types? Math.Net Numerics

Tags: c#, matrix, vector, numeric, math.net

Excuse my ignorance, but are vectors and matrices reference or value types? Not sure if that makes a difference, but I am referring to those created from an array?

I tried to look it up online quickly, but couldn't find the answer.

I tried a few things in my code that made me conclude they are reference types, but being the beginner I am, I wanted to confirm from the experts.

Comment: As a "teach a person to fish" comment: if you are using Visual Studio, right-click on a type name (like `Vector`) and choose _Peek Definition_. It should show you the definition like @gurustron does below. If it's a class, it's a reference type. If it's a struct, it's a value type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Math.NET Numerics [`Vector`](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/5a556371b5c3caea3427066800b8b7536b648fc7/src/Numerics/LinearAlgebra/Vector.cs#L44) and [`Matrix`](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/5a556371b5c3caea3427066800b8b7536b648fc7/src/Numerics/LinearAlgebra/Matrix.cs#L45) are reference types:

```cs
public abstract partial class Vector<T> : IFormattable, IEquatable<Vector<T>>, IList, IList<T>, ICloneable
        where T : struct, IEquatable<T>, IFormattable

public abstract partial class Matrix<T> : IFormattable, IEquatable<Matrix<T>>, ICloneable
        where T : struct, IEquatable<T>, IFormattable
```